# SQL Help Finding Max total value

Tags: sql

I need help finding the total points of a player and Team name based on this table:

```
Tbl.STATS [Match_ID,Player_ID,Points_Scored,Team_Name]
```

Any advice or help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can a player play for multiple teams (transfers)? What do you mean "MAX total"? `MAX` and `SUM` are two different things. Also what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: A player can play for multiple teams via a TRANSFERS entity, but it's not needed in this instance. This would be for the current stats post transfer season. I'm using ORACLE 2007.

Comment: So are you looking for the single player/team combination that has scored the most points in total or something different to that?

Comment: I'm looking to find the player that scored the most total points and what team the player is on.

Answer (score 2):

All players on all teams

```
select player_id, team_name, sum(points_scored) sum_score
from stats
group by player_id, team_name
order by sum_score desc
```

A player and team name (for example, Bob playing for Eagles, so not considering when Bob played for Sharks)

```
select sum(points_scored) sum_score
from stats
where player_id = 1 and team_name = 'Eagles'
```

But the question asks something else again, so going by the question, the MAX total score:

```
select max(sum_score) MaxTotalScore
from
(
    select player_id, team_name, sum(points_scored) sum_score
    from stats
    group by player_id, team_name
) X
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT player_id, team_name, sum(points_scored) FROM STATS Group by player_id, team_name

Answer (score 0):

> "I'm looking to find the player that
>   scored the most total points and what
>   team the player is on."

I don't normally dabble in the Oracle tag but I believe this should work!

```
WITH T AS
(
SELECT Player_ID, 
       Team_Name, 
       SUM(Points_Scored) OVER (PARTITION BY Player_ID) AS Points_Total
FROM Tbl.STATS 
), T2 AS
(
SELECT Player_ID, 
       Team_Name, 
       Points_Total,
       RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Points_Total DESC) AS RN
FROM T       
)
SELECT Player_ID, 
       Team_Name, 
       Points_Total
FROM T2 
WHERE RN=1
```

Comment: Thanks! I also have SQL Server, and I'm trying to figure it out there as well. Sorry for being a pain.